# Why isn't chrome running this javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I run this in Chrome (ver 2), it doesn't return the string, but it works in Firefox (ver 3).  Why is this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function disp_prompt() {
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
    if (name!=null && name!="") {
        document.write("Hello " + name + "! How are you today?");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="disp_prompt()" value="Display a prompt box" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can shorten your 'if (name != null && name != "")' statement to 'if (name)'.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To append content to a document, you should only call `document.write()` during the <script>-block parsing phase.

If you have a call to `document.write` somewhere where it executes outside that context, such as in your event handler, there is no parsing going on, so nowhere for that string `'foo'` to go.

What should happen according to the [original JavaScript reference](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/document.htm#1221642) is:

> Event handlers execute after the original document closes, so the write method implicitly opens a new document of mimeType text/html if you do not explicitly issue a document.open method in the event handler.

That is, it assumes you've made a mistake and meant to do:

```
document.open('text/html');
document.write(html);
```

Which replaces the entire document with new content. You'll also notice that because you didn't finish that off by calling:

```
document.close();
```

...in Firefox, the ‘loading’ throbber is still animating, expecting more content to be written to the document (but it never comes).

In this case, you are `document.write()`ing a string:

```
Hello bobince! How are you today?
```

that is clearly not a valid HTML document. Chrome (and Safari, which behaves the same) is trying to parse it as an HTML document, but fails because it is non-whitespace text content outside the document element (<html>), which is not allowed. If you put some tags in the name input:

```
Hello <em>bobince</em>! How are you today?
```

You'll see everything outside the <em> element is discarded. Firefox and IE manage to apply their “fix up text outside any element” broken-HTML-rule to save you, but Chrome doesn't.

If you want to `document.write()` a new document, you should make sure it is indeed a complete document:

```
<html><head><title>Greetings</title><body><p>Hello bobince! How are you today?</p></body></html>
```

Or, if you want to `document.write()` a text string, you should theoretically call:

```
document.open('text/plain');
```

before the write(). But beware, the mimetype parameter is not supported by Chrome or Safari; they'll always treat what you write as HTML.

In any case, **you probably don't want to be using this method**. If you want to add to (or change) the existing page you should normally be using DOM methods, such as setting the text on a status output div, or replacing the body contents using innerHTML.

`document.write()` is needed in a few places (in particular, when you are creating a new window or frame from scratch), but otherwise it's generally the wrong thing and should be viewed with suspicion.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! (I wish there'd be an option to give 10 votes to a single answer: I've been a whole week searching and reading on how to solve javascript execution of an ajax retrieved page replacing whole document... If only I had searched for document.write javascript execution issues on chrome before!!)

Answer (score 9):

don't use document.write. if you change it to soemthing like

```
if (name != null && name != "") {
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "Hello " + name + "! How are you today?";
}

<body>
<input ...

<div id='foo'> </div>
</body>
```

document.write has pretty strange behavior. Where do you expect the text to be written to?

Comment: I think there's an extra bracket after "! How are you today?".

Comment: Oh.  I just got started learning javascript via web tutorials.  thanks for the tip!

Comment: I thought the text was just supposed to be written to the browser window.

Comment: @KentFredric once or twice i've reached a point in which document.write is the only solution that worked for me, so keep in mind that sometimes it might make your life easier

Answer (score 2):

Just add some paragraph tags in the write call:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function disp_prompt() {
    var name = window.prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
    if (name) {
        window.document.write("<p>Hello " + name + "! How are you today?<\/p>");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="disp_prompt()" value="Display a prompt box" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late to the party, but I saw a violation in regards to `document.write()` in Chrome DevTools with a link.  Needless to say, it was an interesting read.

**What's This About?**

Starting in Chrome v55, Chrome is going to start blocking `document.write()` under a very select set of circumstances.  You can read about it here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

This should **only** come into effect for users who are on a 2G cellular connection, and possibly other types of connections which are slow.  Here's an excerpt of the article in question:

> With this data in mind, Chrome, starting with version 55, intervenes
> on behalf of all users when we detect this known-bad pattern by
> changing how document.write() is handled in Chrome (See Chrome
> Status). Specifically Chrome will not execute the  elements
> injected via document.write() when all of the following conditions are
> met:
>
> 1. The user is on a slow connection, specifically when the user is on 2G. (In the future, the change might be extended to other users on
>    slow connections, such as slow 3G or slow WiFi.)
> 2. The document.write() is in a top level document. The intervention does not apply to document.written scripts within iframes as they
>    don't block the rendering of the main page.
> 3. The script in the document.write() is parser-blocking. Scripts with the 'async' or 'defer' attributes will still execute.
> 4. The script is not hosted on the same site. In other words, Chrome will not intervene for scripts with a matching eTLD+1 (e.g. a script
>    hosted on js.example.org inserted on [www.example.org](http://www.example.org)).
> 5. The script is not already in the browser HTTP cache. Scripts in the cache will not incur a network delay and will still execute.
> 6. The request for the page is not a reload. Chrome will not intervene if the user triggered a reload and will execute the page as
>    normal.
>
> Third party snippets sometimes use document.write() to load scripts.
> Fortunately, most third parties provide asynchronous loading
> alternatives, which allow third party scripts to load without blocking
> the display of the rest of the content on the page.

So if your `document.write()` meets all 6 criteria, then Chrome will block it.  You should be able to see the message in DevTools when it happens.

**The OP's Question**

To address the OP's question, in order to use `document.write()` you have to use `document.open("text/html")` first.  After you're done writing to the document, you need to use `document.close()`.  If you're just going to write plain text, then use `document.open("text/plain")`.  However, I recently read somewhere that Chrome ignores the mimetype and forces text/html.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function disp_prompt() {
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
    if (name!=null && name!="") {
        document.open("text/plain");
        document.write("Hello " + name + "! How are you today?");
        document.close();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="disp_prompt()" value="Display a prompt box" />

</body>
</html>
```

**--OR--**

You can modify the text that you write to include proper HTML like this:

```
document.write('<html><head></head><body>Hello ' + name + '! How are you today?</body></html>');
```

Don't forget to add `document.open()` and `document.close()` in all cases.