# Writing to the DOM on body onload not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, onload

In Google Chrome, the following code snippet:

```
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>              
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        <!--
            function onBodyLoad()
            {               
                var x = 42;
                document.writeln("x = " + x);
                alert("on load");
            }
        -->
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = "onBodyLoad()"></body>
</html>
```

Is not writing

> x = 42

to the document. The alert however is displayed. The text and the alert are both displayed in IE8 and FF 3.5. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's a Webkit bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587 There are workarounds mentioned in the answers already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a `document.close()` after `document.writeln()`:

```
            function onBodyLoad()
            {                               
                    var x = 42;
                    document.writeln("x = " + x);
                    alert("on load");
                    document.close();
            }
```

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762416/why-isnt-chrome-running-this-javascript) as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Check and see if this [post](http://www.eveningblog.com/archive/javascript-documentwriteln-and-chrome/) helps. I dont use chrome and you have to add `document.close();`

`;` missing in `document.writeln("x = " + x)` (?)

Comment: Oops, that was just a typo in my submission, the ; is there in the original source.

Comment: No it wasn't. Someone added it after your post.

Comment: By "original source", I meant on my machine =)